# Check if numbers in a vector are alternating in R

Tags: r

i need to check if the first number of a vector is smaller than the second number and the second number is greater than the third number and so on. I got so far that i can calculate the differences of the numbers of a vector like this:

```
n <- sample(3) #may n = 132
diff(n) # outputs 2 -1
```

I need to check if the first number is positive, the second negative etc. The problem i have is that i need the program to do it for a vector of length n. How can i implement this?

As it is not very clear what i am trying to do here i will give a better example:

May v be a vector c(1,2,4,3).

I need to check if the first number of the vector is smaller than the second, the second greater than the third, the third smaller than the fourth.

So i need to check if 1 < 2 > 4 < 3. (This vector wouldn´t meet the requirements) Every number i will get will be > 0 and is guaranteed to just be there once.

This process needs to be generalized to a given n which is > 0 and a natural number.

Comment: How do you want the `0` values to be?

Comment: if any of the values is 0 then the vector doesnt meet my requirements and the for loop which creates a vectir every iteration would continue

Comment: So i nthe example, it is `1 < 2 > 4 < 3`, Why is 2 > 4 ?  With this vector `v <- c(1, 2, 4, 3)` what is the expected output?

Comment: Sir, it is just an example of how the vector needs to be checked. As i wrote in the question, that example wouldn´t be right so it would not be considered further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to find whether there are alternative postive, negative difference, then

```
all(rle(as.vector(tapply(n, as.integer(gl(length(n),
         2, length(n))), FUN = diff)))$lengths==1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Also, as @digEmAll commented and the variation of my initial response

```
all(rle(sign(diff(n)) > 0)$lengths == 1)
```

#### data

```
n <- c(1, 2, 4, 3)
```

Comment: what does the rle() method do here?

Comment: @NumanTakács  It is based on assumption that you need to have alternating positive and negative differences.  From your post, it is not clear about the expected.  `rle` is used to find if the lengths of adjacent positive or negative elements are equal to 1 or not

Comment: @NumanTakács  If you use `diff(n)#
[1]  1  2 -1` The first two values are positive

Comment: Yes the vector in my example wouldnt be considered. Though 132 would, because the requirements are met.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get how this is the correct answer... for 1,2,4,3 should return false... shouldn't it ?

Comment: Shouldn't be simply : `all(rle(sign(diff(n)) > 0)$lengths == 1)`

Comment: Then the question should be closed because unclear, I mean, OP clearly states "1 < 2 > 4 < 3. (This vector wouldn´t meet the requirements) " and then accept TRUE for that vector ??

Comment: My initial response was `all(rle(diff(n) > 0)$lengths==1)` and perhaps the `sign` makes the difference

Comment: @akrun: nothing against your answer... I'm not downvoting you neither flagging you, I'm just wondering how the OP can accept an answer which returns TRUE for an example vector he clearly states does not meet the requirements...

Comment: @digEmAll  May be this answer meets the OP's expected

Comment: @akrun: yeah... whatever... ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
v <- c(1, 2, 4, 3)
all(sign(diff(v)) == c(1, -1))
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In sign(diff(v)) == c(1, -1) :
# longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

We can safely ignore the warning message, since we make deliberate use of "recycling" (which means `c(1, -1)` is implicitly repeated to match the length of `sign(diff(v))`).

*Edit:* taking @digEmAll's comment into account, if you want to allow a negative difference rather than a positive one at the start of the sequence, then this naive change should do it:

```
diffs <- sign(diff(v))
all(diffs == c(1, -1)) || all(diffs == c(-1, 1))
```

Comment: This won't work if the first value is greater than the second...but maybe is not acceptable for the OP...

Answer (score 0):

The function I use to check for alternating signs is:

```r
isAlt <- function(x) all(abs(diff(sign(x))) == 2)
```

This works because if the signs alternate, then you are either seeing -1 against 1 or the opposite, whose difference is always absolute magnitude 2. If two entries had the same sign, the difference of their signs would be 0. In your case, you would run `diff` on the vector first to convert "larger vs. smaller" to ">0 vs < 0".

Here is an example of how it works.

```r
isAlt <- function(x) all(abs(diff(sign(x))) == 2)

test1 <- 1:10
test2 <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6)
# Wrap test2 around to check large --> small
test3 <- c(test2[-1], 1)

> isAlt(diff(test1))
[1] FALSE
> isAlt(diff(test2))
[1] TRUE
> isAlt(diff(test3))
[1] TRUE
```

For timings, I will compare against @akrun's version. His has the benefit of building the `diff` into the function so it can be called on any vector. However,  my version has the benefit of using *only* vectorized functions and thus doesn't need any `*apply` calls, which is why it is roughly 7--10 times faster. Granted, it's measured in microseconds, but if you were to be calling this 10,000+ times inside another procedure that may add up.

```r
isAlt.akrun <- function(x) {
  all(rle(as.vector(tapply(x, as.integer(gl(length(x), 2, length(x))),
                           FUN = diff)))$lengths==1)
}

library(microbenchmark)

bmT1 <- microbenchmark(isAlt(diff(test1)), isAlt.akrun(test1),
                       check = 'identical', control = list(order = 'block'),
                       times = 1000L)

bmT2 <- microbenchmark(isAlt(diff(test2)), isAlt.akrun(test2),
                       check = 'identical', control = list(order = 'block'),
                       times = 1000L)

bmT3 <- microbenchmark(isAlt(diff(test3)), isAlt.akrun(test3),
                       check = 'identical', control = list(order = 'block'),
                       times = 1000L)

print(bmT1, order = 'median')
Unit: microseconds
               expr  min   lq     mean median   uq    max neval cld
 isAlt(diff(test1)) 11.6 12.0  13.0575   12.2 12.6   69.5  1000  a 
 isAlt.akrun(test1) 88.6 93.1 104.4684   95.1 98.4 3239.8  1000   b

print(bmT2, order = 'median')
Unit: microseconds
               expr  min   lq     mean median    uq    max neval cld
 isAlt(diff(test2)) 11.3 11.8  12.4792   11.9  12.2  178.7  1000  a 
 isAlt.akrun(test2) 89.8 93.7 101.3557   97.1 100.0 2447.4  1000   b

Unit: microseconds
               expr  min   lq    mean median uq    max neval cld
 isAlt(diff(test3)) 11.2 11.6 12.0837   11.8 12   52.2  1000  a 
 isAlt.akrun(test3) 85.8 91.8 98.6858   94.2 97 2391.8  1000   b
```